# Cannot resolve TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, undefined, dotenv

I have this code. WebStorm shows, that there is error `TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'`. I have installed `dotenv` and `@types/dotenv` but still have this error. How to I fix it?

Here is code:

```
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';

import { JwtPayload } from "../interfaces/jwt";

const privateKey = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname + "../../../keys/private.pem"));
const publicKey = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname + "../../../keys/public.pem"));

export = {
  sign: (payload: JwtPayload) => {
    try {
      return jwt.sign(
        payload,
        {
          key: privateKey,
          passphrase: process.env.JWT_PASSPHRASE.toString()
        },
        {
          algorithm: "RS256",
          expiresIn: "30m"
        }
      )
    } catch (e) {
      //
    }
  },
```

Also want to say, that I have the same version on `dotenv` and `@types/dotenv` - `^8.2.0`. I was trying to add this module like this, but it doesn't work:

```
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config()
```

Comment: What is possibly undefined? How is dotenv related?

Comment: I don't really know, this is what WebStorm shows and just title of this error.

Comment: There's no way to begin to help without any idea regarding where the error is occuring.

Comment: This error is everywhere where I have `process.env.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by setting `strictNullChecks` to false in `tsconfig.json`:

```
"strictNullChecks": false,
```